# AWS s3 sync data transfer charges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I don't understand how AWS charges for S3 sync more than I expected. The view is that I have a S3 bucket with about 5TB of data and 200 million objects inside it. Now I need to replicate this bucket with each objects, from another account in another region. So, can anyone help to figure out how much it will cost. Also is there any other way to replicate a S3 bucket better than a sync? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using [S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html)?

Comment: What do you mean by "more than I expected"? What did you get charged, and what did you 'expect' to be charged?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, AWS charges for data transfer between S3 buckets over network. It is understandable, but they also charges separately for each request. I mean AWS also charge for each request of object. After all there are 200 millions of objects. And this increases the cost a lot. So is there any other way to reduce costs.

Comment: Your buckets are in different Regions, so they will incur Data Transfer costs. You have millions of objects, so there are millions of requests required. You can reduce costs by transferring less data or transferring fewer objects, such as combining the objects into a smaller number of objects or compressing the files. Why are you wanting to duplicate the objects between regions?